# KIBANA ElasticQuery from java

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, get, kibana

I would like to fire this REST GET API cal from java

```
 curl -x 'http://localhost:9200' -d '{
     "size": 0,
     "aggs": {
       "2": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "message_user_uid",
           "size": 10,
           "order": {
             "_count": "desc"
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "query": {
       "filtered": {
         "query": {
           "query_string": {
             "query": "_key: \"my-demo-exchange-*\" AND message_message: \"success\"",
             "analyze_wildcard": true
           }
         },
         "filter": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "range": {
                   "@timestamp": {
                     "gte": 1457261289759,
                     "lte": 1457347689760,
                     "format": "epoch_millis"
                   }
                 }
               }
             ],
             "must_not": []
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "highlight": {
       "pre_tags": [
         "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
       ],
       "post_tags": [
         "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
       ],
       "fields": {
         "*": {}
       },
       "require_field_match": false,
       "fragment_size": 2147483647
     }
    }'
```

JAVA CODE

```
try {
            URL url = new URL("above curl expression");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));
            String output="",line;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    output+=line+"\n";
            }
            conn.disconnect();
            System.out.println(output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it gives an error for

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: curl -x
```

So how can I fetch the response from the server for such kind of elastic search.
I found lots on the google and also on stack but not got any proper response.
I want that this java program should run this query and return me that output.
But this SIMPLE REST GET Call program is not working in this case.

Now I am using this code

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("kibana host IP Address"), 9200));
        GetResponse getResponse=client.prepareGet().execute().get();
        System.out.println(getResponse.toString());
```

But it gives me an error

```
Error : None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{host IP}{host IP:9200}]
```

Comment: Are you sure about your URL in `new URL("localhost:9200/");`is this really what you have compiled? Besides for curl you need to write `curl -XPOST` and not only `curl -x`

Comment: Actually there is some URL but I am not allowed to post that URL on stack so I have kept it as localhost and I have also tried with -XGET but same issue comes

Comment: Can you make sure that you don't have "curl ..." inside your URL constructor `new URL("...")`? You just need an URL starting with "http://...". It looks like what you have is `new URL("curl -x GET http://.../")` but you simply need ``new URL("http://.../")``

Comment: new URL("")in this constructor I have passed full curl code which is given in question and then it throws me an error for no protocol : curl

Comment: I have modified question and posted new code which uses Elastic Get Calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you don't have an occurrence of "curl ..." inside your URL constructor.

You just need an URL starting with `"http://..."` although it looks like what you have is

```
new URL("curl -x GET http://.../")
```

but you simply need

```
new URL("http://.../")
```

`curl` is a standalone command that you run in a shell, it has nothing to do with Java and it is not a valid protocol either.

**UPDATE**

In order to send the query in the payload you need to change your code to this:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9200");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    writer.write(" input your query in here");
    writer.close();
    // proceed to read the response
```

Comment: then how can I append -d     parameters in url?

Comment: with this I am getting this error java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: " {
                 "gte": 1457261289759,
                 "lte": 1457347689760,
                 "format": "epoch_millis"
               }
             }
           }
         ],
         "must_not": []
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "highlight": {
   "pre_tags": [
     "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
   ],
   "post_tags": [
     "@"

Comment: it gives malformed url exception for url from -d to end

Comment: it gives "Connection timed out: connect" on updates answer but if I curl it, it works fine

Comment: You've replaced `"http://localhost:9200"` with your own URL in the URL constructor, right?

Comment: If curl works and your Java code times out, not sure what's wrong, hard to tell without being able to reproduce the problem. That code works fine for me. Can you show your URL without the host part which you want to keep private?

Comment: Hi, It works nowm I have just restarted ElasticSearch and it works fine. Now what if I would like to delete in elasticsearch. $ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' This works but how to make it in java

Comment: Glad it finally worked out. I suggest you ask another question for the DELETE as it is a different issue.